# creatScaled Bitmap low quality

Tags: android, bitmap, image-scaling

hello guys i'm having a problem with scaling an image to square size. 612 * 612

first i'm getting the image as cache from the imageview and then i'm converting it to Bitmap image.

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    save = view.getDrawingCache();
```

then i'm using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` as below

```
     Bitmap a = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(save, 612, 612, true);
```

it works as i want it but when the image scaled it lose its  quality

here is how i `compress` the image to save it / share it

```
        a.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

i'm sharing it through my application to Instagram to fit inside instagram cropping tool but the image always will be low quality. 
can anyone tell me how do i scale / resize  the image dimension without losing its quality or to fit inside instagram cropping tool without losing quality. thanks